# how to create React search filter for search multiple object key values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I want to create a search filter for my data array.it has multiple objects and keys like this one,

```
[
    {
        "fname": "Jayne",
        "lname": "Washington",
        "email": "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        "gender": "female"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Peterson",
        "lname": "Dalton",
        "email": "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Velazquez",
        "lname": "Calderon",
        "email": "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Norman",
        "lname": "Reed",
        "email": "normanreed@exposa.com",
        "gender": "male"
    }
]
```

I want search filter search anywhere on this array.
ex: when I type input box I want to search anywhere inside an object. like fname,lname,email,gender

how can i do it? please help me

If I want to restrict the search for only first and last names how to do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can keep a value `filter` in your component state and use that to see if it is contained as a substring in any of the array element properties.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filter: "",
    data: [
      {
        fname: "Jayne",
        lname: "Washington",
        email: "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        fname: "Peterson",
        lname: "Dalton",
        email: "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Velazquez",
        lname: "Calderon",
        email: "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ filter: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { filter, data } = this.state;
    const lowercasedFilter = filter.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input value={filter} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {filteredData.map(item => (
          <div key={item.email}>
            <div>
              {item.fname} {item.lname} - {item.gender} - {item.email}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Searching for male will also match female. Need to use regex for this. ^1

Comment: @BhojendraNepal No need for regex. You can use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) if your just want to match from the beginning of the string, but OP didn't say anything about that, so I assumed `includes` type search was wanted.

Comment: OP has stated to filter fname,lname,email,gender. So, this means searching for male should not match female. Ah, yeah startsWith is cool.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Not necessarily. fe`male` contains `male`, and if that is not what OP wants, he can tell me otherwise in a comment.

Comment: It would be good if you provide both example (not necessarily be full) in your post. (A nice answer)

Comment: @Tholle your code works perfectly. thanks for your help.i didn't want to search beginning of the word.I want to search anywhere of words.this code is correct for my own thanks again for your help

Comment: this code is for creating data table I think if we add the startsWith its does not match to this.if I wrong please correct me

Comment: @GihanRangana `startsWith` can be a nice alternative to `includes` if you only want to match for the beginning of the string, e.g. filter `male` would not match fe`male` like it does now. I think you don't need `startsWith`.

Comment: @Tholle oh I forgot one. I changed this line for when if search filed is empty
`x[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) || !searchText`

Comment: If the data/JSON has non-string values like a boolean or float then this code will break. Convert the object into string like this:
`item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)`

Comment: Nice answer. I managed to implmenent something like this before already but the data structure I wanted to return values for would match something like this:
`{
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male",
        address: {
            postcode: "W2 6AW",
            street: "Jasmine Street"
      }
}`

If the user searched for either "W2 6AW" or "Jasmine" it should return this object. How can that be achieved?

Otherwise, a very nice solution.

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: hello ,I think the handle change should not be triggered always, so can we use debounce for it?,like is it possible to add here?

Answer (score 0):

**Search filter for multiple objects key values and also highlights the search terms**

Implemented two functions - `highlighter` and `filterHandler`.

`filterHandler` function filters the data based on the input given and then it sends the filtered data to highlighter function for highlighting.

`highlighter` function takes two arguments obj and input and it returns highlightable HTML code as a string.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: "",
    fData: [{
        fname: "Jayne",
        lname: "Washington",
        email: "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        fname: "Peterson",
        lname: "Dalton",
        email: "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Velazquez",
        lname: "Calderon",
        email: "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      }
    ],
    data: [{
        fname: "Jayne",
        lname: "Washington",
        email: "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        fname: "Peterson",
        lname: "Dalton",
        email: "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Velazquez",
        lname: "Calderon",
        email: "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      }
    ]
  };


  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    }, this.filterHandler);
  };

  highlighter = (obj, lowercasedInput) => {
    let rawObj = obj.replace(`<span class='highlight'>`, '').replace(`</span>`, '');

    if (rawObj.indexOf(lowercasedInput) != -1) {
      const startIndex = rawObj.indexOf(lowercasedInput);
      const endIndex = startIndex - 1 + lowercasedInput.length;

      if (startIndex != 0) {
        return rawObj.slice(0, startIndex) + `<span class='highlight'>${lowercasedInput}</span>` + rawObj.slice(endIndex + 1, rawObj.length);
      } else {
        return rawObj.slice(0, startIndex) + `<span class='highlight'>${lowercasedInput}</span>` + rawObj.slice(endIndex + 1, rawObj.length);
      }
    } else {
      return rawObj
    }
  }


  filterHandler = () => {
    const {
      input,
      data
    } = this.state;
    const lowercasedInput = input.toLowerCase();

    const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedInput)
      );
    });

    let highlightFD = [];
    filteredData.map((values, index) => {
      highlightFD.push({ ...values
      });
    })


    if (lowercasedInput.trim().length > 0) {
      highlightFD.map((val, index) => {
        for (let key in val) {
          highlightFD[index][key] = this.highlighter(val[key].toLowerCase(), lowercasedInput);
        }
      });
    }

    this.setState({
      fData: highlightFD
    });

  }

  render() {
    const {
      input,
      fData
    } = this.state;



    return ( <
        div >
        <
        input value = {
          input
        }
        onChange = {
          this.handleChange
        }
        /> {
        fData.map(item => ( <div key ={item.email} className = "results" >
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.fname}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.lname}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.gender}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.email}}/>  
        </div >
        ))
      } </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.results {
  display: flex
}

span {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Note:** dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

To read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

**Using Regular expressions :**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: "",
    fData: [{
        fname: "Jayne",
        lname: "Washington",
        email: "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        fname: "Peterson",
        lname: "Dalton",
        email: "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Velazquez",
        lname: "Calderon",
        email: "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      }
    ],
    data: [{
        fname: "Jayne",
        lname: "Washington",
        email: "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
        gender: "female"
      },
      {
        fname: "Peterson",
        lname: "Dalton",
        email: "petersondalton@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Velazquez",
        lname: "Calderon",
        email: "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      },
      {
        fname: "Norman",
        lname: "Reed",
        email: "normanreed@exposa.com",
        gender: "male"
      }
    ]
  };


  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    }, this.filterHandler);
  };

  highlighter = (obj, lowercasedInput) => {
    let rawObj = obj.replace(`<span class='highlight'>`, '').replace(`</span>`, '');

    if (rawObj.indexOf(lowercasedInput) != -1) {
      const startIndex = rawObj.indexOf(lowercasedInput);
      const endIndex = startIndex - 1 + lowercasedInput.length;

      if (startIndex != 0) {
        return rawObj.slice(0, startIndex) + `<span class='highlight'>${lowercasedInput}</span>` + rawObj.slice(endIndex + 1, rawObj.length);
      } else {
        return rawObj.slice(0, startIndex) + `<span class='highlight'>${lowercasedInput}</span>` + rawObj.slice(endIndex + 1, rawObj.length);
      }
    } else {
      return rawObj
    }
  }


  filterHandler = () => {
    const {
      input,
      data
    } = this.state;
    const lowercasedInput = input.toLowerCase();

    const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>{
         const regex= new RegExp(`^${lowercasedInput.trim()}`,'i');
            return regex.test(item[key].toLowerCase()) ;
         }
      );
    });

    let highlightFD = [];
    filteredData.map((values, index) => {
      highlightFD.push({ ...values
      });
    })


    if (lowercasedInput.trim().length > 0) {
      highlightFD.map((val, index) => {
        for (let key in val) {
          highlightFD[index][key] = this.highlighter(val[key].toLowerCase(), lowercasedInput);
        }
      });
    }

    this.setState({
      fData: highlightFD
    });

  }

  render() {
    const {
      input,
      fData
    } = this.state;



    return ( <
        div >
        <
        input value = {
          input
        }
        onChange = {
          this.handleChange
        }
        /> {
        fData.map(item => ( <div key ={item.email} className = "results" >
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.fname}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.lname}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.gender}}/>&nbsp;|&nbsp; 
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{__html: item.email}}/>  
        </div >
        ))
      } </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.results {
  display: flex
}

span {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fData.filter((person) => {
  return object
    .value(person)
    .join('')
    .toLowerCase()
    .include(searchinput.toLowerCase())
})
```

Here `searchinput` is the value you are typing in your input that is controlled by state.