# Search form multiple fields javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, algorithm

Let's say there is an array of objects like,

```
[
    {
        "fname": "Anne",
        "lname": "Walker",
        "email": "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Peterson",
        "lname": "Dalton",
        "email": "petersondalton@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Velazquez",
        "lname": "Calderon",
        "email": "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Norman",
        "lname": "Reed",
        "email": "normanreed@exposa.com",
    }
]
```

I want to create a search filter which searches by the only fname and lname.
There was a question like this before asked but it search through all the fields

[how to create React search filter for search multiple object key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801907/how-to-create-react-search-filter-for-search-multiple-object-key-values)

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: good job for looking for existing solution. That said, in the link you provided, the filtering occurs on a given field provided by user (see this.setState). Either fname or lname or email. Is this fine for you or you want to apply several filter at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ok?

```
const json = [
    {
        "fname": "Anne",
        "lname": "Walker",
        "email": "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Peterson",
        "lname": "Dalton",
        "email": "petersondalton@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Velazquez",
        "lname": "Calderon",
        "email": "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Norman",
        "lname": "Reed",
        "email": "normanreed@exposa.com",
    }
];
function search(str) {
    const keyword = str.toLowerCase();
    return json.filter(x => x.fname.toLowerCase().includes(keyword) || x.lname.toLowerCase().includes(keyword));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, If you want to search for a keyword that matches either the lname or fname, use the code above. But if you need to write a function that searches the objects based on both fname AND lname, you must use @corrado4eyes 's answer.
Also notice that I use .toLowerCase() to search case-insensitive. If you need your search to be Case-Sensitive remove the usage of .toLowerCase() 
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash library. Use find or filter functions.
Find - for single result and
Filter for multiple results
Example-

```
let _ = require('lodash');
let data = [
    {
        "fname": "Anne",
        "lname": "Walker",
        "email": "jaynewashington@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Peterson",
        "lname": "Dalton",
        "email": "petersondalton@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Velazquez",
        "lname": "Calderon",
        "email": "velazquezcalderon@exposa.com",
    },
    {
        "fname": "Norman",
        "lname": "Reed",
        "email": "normanreed@exposa.com",
    }
]
let result = _.find(data, { fname: 'Norman', lname: 'Reed'})
```

Another alternative without library

```
let res = data.find(o => o.fname == "Norman" && o.lname == "Reed")
console.log(res)
```

Comment: No need to include a library for a basic requirement. Can be achieved using `Array.prototype.find`

Comment: Thanks people, For your time

Answer (score 1):

You should propose an example you tried and say "Hey guys I tried this on these data, but it did not work.". However is an array of object, so what you could do is:

```
const magicFunction = (name, lastName, array) => {
    return array.filter((el) => el.fname === name && el.lname === lastName);
}
```